# Kubernetes (GKE) internal lookups cannot be resolved

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I am having an issue with Kubernetes on GKE. I am unable to resolve services by name. I got an `drone-server` service running which is connected to a single pod. The ingress connected to the service is successfully connecting but when trying to do for example a `nslookup` from a `busybox` pod is it unable to resolve the hostname.

**Services:**

```
$ k get services -n drone
NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
drone-server   ClusterIP   10.39.242.23    <none>        80/TCP    2d
drone-vault    ClusterIP   10.39.248.166   <none>        80/TCP    40m
```

**Busybox nslookup:**

```
$ kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup drone-server
Server:    10.39.240.10
Address 1: 10.39.240.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

nslookup: can't resolve 'drone-server'
```

When i try to lookup `kubernetes.default` am I getting a local address back:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    10.39.240.10
Address 1: 10.39.240.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      kubernetes.default
Address 1: 10.39.240.1 kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
```

**Resolv config:**

`/etc/resolv.conf` seems to be configured correctly (the nameserver is matching the kube-dns service cluster ip).

```
$ kubectl exec -ti busybox -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.39.240.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local europe-west3-a.c.cluster-a8e6d9e252b63e03.internal c.cluster-a8e6d9e252b63e03.internal google.internal
options ndots:5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `drone-server` service is in the `drone` namespace and you're trying to nslookup from default namespace. You need to provide the namespace also in command as follows:

```
kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup drone-server.drone
```

This is because your busybox in the default namespace and it tries to look drone-server in same namespace.

Comment: Thank you very much. I also just figured it out  [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-routing-internal-services-through-fqdn-d98db92b79d3)

Comment: Hi @JeroenRinzema Welcome to SO. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider `accepting` it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. However, There is no obligation to do this.